# HTACCESS Redirect Issue on WordPress with folder as root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am experiencing some strange behavior on my HTACCESS file.

I have a WordPress blog installed at this location: h[ttp://www.domain.com/blog/](http://www.domain.com/blog/)

when I leave out the last / from the URL eg. http://www.domain.com/blog

the HTACCESS file redirects me here: http://www.domain.com/httpdocs/blog/ (404 page not found)

This URL should resolve to: http://www.domain.com/blog/

How can I achieve this with HTACCESS file?

Here is my HTACCESS File in the blog folder (WordPress Root):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post you htaccess rewrite rules

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: still not working - still takes me to same URL http://www.domain.com/httpdocs/blog/